# com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.<init>(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:428)

Tags: android, appium, android-sdk-manager, appium-desktop

Error while installing SDK manager.

I downloaded zip file from the below location for SDK to install in command line.

And while following the user guide steps facing the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by Windows Inside Version, or the Path setting. 
Going back to win10 version and resetting the path solved the same problem.